# Plot a customized state map in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to plot cities within some of the states of USA. The Cities would appear as dots and the size of the dot would depend on the values for each city, mentioned in a separate column, in my data-set. Also, I have in my data set a category column where the cities have been put into categories "Good", "Bad" and "Average". The colour of the city would depend on the category. I have been able to code this far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
all_states <- map_data("state")
c <- ggplot()
c <- c + geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),colour="gray", fill="white" )
c
cities <- read.csv("D:/R/R data final/cities.csv")
View(cities)
c <- ggplot()
c <- c + geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),colour="gray", fill="white" )
c <- c + geom_point( data=cities, aes(x=long, y=lat, size =  value), color="red") + scale_size(name="Value")
c <- c + geom_text( data=cities, hjust=0.5, vjust=-0.5, aes(x=long, y=lat, label=Category), colour="black", size=4 )
c
```

I have been able to plot the map and the points. but the points lie outside the map and are crowded together. Is it possible to plot these points at their respective lat long within the map and have their color based on their category?

all_states data is from R library. Cities data has columns: CITY, STATE, lat, long, value, category.

Please help.

Comment: it's complaining about not finding the variable label! 
Read your own statement about Cities Data, which has columns CITY,STATE... 
Perhaps label=CITY?

Comment: Yup. Your text says "colour of the city would depend on the category", and your code says `colour = "black"`. In your last code line, try `aes(x=long, y=lat, label=CITY, colour=category)`.